# Moving the cursor through long soft-wrapped lines in Vim

Tags: vim, text, formatting

I'd like to use VIM to write papers for some classes I'm in.  The problem I'm having is with the formatting of lines in the editor.  If I don't explicitly break the end of a line with the enter key, when I try to move the cursor through the text, it skips multiple lines if I have a sentence that spans more than one line.

Is there any way to make it so that the cursor will be able to move through the text akin to the way it does in most word processors?

Comment: some more information here in addition to the answers: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Move_cursor_by_display_lines_when_wrapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the following in vim command line:

```
:set nowrap
```

Comment: I also recommend `:set textwidth=80` for automatic line wrapping.

Comment: That command doesn't seem to be doing anything, but I can see why you'd want something like that.  Any idea why it might not be working for me?

Comment: The textwidth setting is only applied on new text, it does not reformat your document automatically - but you can use something like gq to do this (see :help gq). Pressing gggqG in normal mode should be fine.

Comment: This just disables soft line wrap and the question is specifically for soft-wrapped lines.

Answer (score 63):

The problem with the often used

```
noremap j gj  
noremap k gk
```

option is, that it breaks the `<vcount>` functionality, if you have lines in your text, which span across multiple lines.
Example: you want `10k` (go UP 10 lines), because you use relative numbers in the sidebar, but theres a multiline with 4 lines height. Therefore you end up effectively at 6 lines (`6k`) above your desired line, which you read from your relative numbers. You'd have to calculate manually! Annoying... Especially if you have multiple multiline between your current position and your desired position - not Vim-*istic*!

I like my `<vcount>` function together with my `:relativenumber`, which is why I wrote the following functions & mapping to solve all problems related to this.
These functions let you use commands like `10j` or `10k` as expected, despite the presence of multilines with all the advantages of using `gj` and `gk` as your default movement mappings:

**Edit:**
I just found the following on reddit, which is so much better then my own solution. This is shortest possible version:

```
nnoremap <expr> j v:count ? 'j' : 'gj'
nnoremap <expr> k v:count ? 'k' : 'gk'
```

*(If you use `noremap` instead of `nnoremap`, then this works in both visual and normal modes)*

"Longer" version for better understanding and completeness:

```
nnoremap <expr> k (v:count == 0 ? 'gk' : 'k')
nnoremap <expr> j (v:count == 0 ? 'gj' : 'j')
```

*source:* http://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/2k4cbr/problem_with_gj_and_gk/

---

**My old solution:**

```
nnoremap <silent> j :<C-U>call Down(v:count)<CR>
vnoremap <silent> j gj

nnoremap <silent> k :<C-U>call Up(v:count)<CR>
vnoremap <silent> k gk

function! Down(vcount)
  if a:vcount == 0
    exe "normal! gj"
  else
    exe "normal! ". a:vcount ."j"
  endif
endfunction

function! Up(vcount)
  if a:vcount == 0
    exe "normal! gk"
  else
    exe "normal! ". a:vcount ."k"
  endif
endfunction
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this horizontally too?

Comment: For the solution found on Reddit, you might want to use `noremap` instead of `nnoremap` so it also works on visual mode.

Answer (score 18):

That's because the default `j` and `k` motions move across *physical lines*, not the visible, soft-wrapped *screen lines* (when you have `:set wrap`). You can use the `gj` and `gk` commands for that.

If you want to default to that behavior, you can remap the default keys by putting this into your `~/.vimrc`:

```
noremap j gj
noremap k gk
```

Comment: Does not work with up/down arrows

Comment: @Trismegistos of course it doesn't this remaps the `j` key to `gj` and `k` to `gk`
If you want to have support for arrow keys, simply add those as remaps
`noremap <Up> gk`
`noremap <Down> gj`

Answer (score 1):

I have found another version of this solution that does more than moving through physical or virtual lines, it also adds jumps bigger than 5 lines to the jump list, allowing us to use Ctrl-o and Ctrl-i.

```
" source: https://www.vi-improved.org/vim-tips/
nnoremap <expr> j v:count ? (v:count > 5 ? "m'" . v:count : '') . 'j' : 'gj'
nnoremap <expr> k v:count ? (v:count > 5 ? "m'" . v:count : '') . 'k' : 'gk'
```

It uses a nested ternary operator to add the jump to the jump list

Answer (score 1):

Solution that I found on internet that works with up and down arrow:

```
imap <silent> <Down> <C-o>gj
imap <silent> <Up> <C-o>gk
nmap <silent> <Down> gj
nmap <silent> <Up> gk
```